# Pair-instability supernovae: how does it happen?

Tags: supernova, pair-production, stellar-evolution

How does the formation of electron positron pairs increase the energy density and softens the EOS?

I trrying to understand the pair instability supernova. In many texts and articles, it is written that the formation of electron positron pairs lead to instability, the energy density is increased and the adiabatic index drops below 4/3 which softens the equation of state.

- How does the formation of electron positron pairs lead to instability?
- How is the energy density increased?
- What does it mean by 'softening of EOS' and how does it happen?